# Making a WCF SOAP service send X requests per second

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I'd like to know if there's a way to configure JMeter so that it send X request per second to my web-service.
The aim is simply to see what's going on with my service.

I am using JMeter-plugins with `jp@gc - Ultimate Thread Group` and `jp@gc - Throughput Shaping Timer` however it seems that I'm missing something since I never see on JMeter that I send X request per second.

I set up `jp@gc - Throughput Shaping Timer` for 5 request / second like this :

```
Start RPS : 5
End RPS : 5
Duration : 30 second
```

Then I set up `jp@gc - Ultimate Thread Group` still for 5 request / second like this :

```
Start Thread Count : 175
Initial Delay : 0 second
Start up Time : 0 second
Hold load for : 40 second
Shutdown time : 0 second
```

Do I do something wrong? Is there some simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using regular thread group instead of Ultimate one.

See :

- http://jmeter-plugins.googlecode.com/svn-history/trunk/examples/ThroughputShapingExample.jmx

Also read this:

- http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer

> How Many Threads I Need To Produce Desired RPS?
>   Threads pool size can be calculated like RPS *  / 1000. The more rate desired the more threads you will need. The more response time service have the more threads you will need.
>   For example, if your service response time may be 2.5sec and target rps is 1230, you have to have 1230 * 2500 / 1000 = 3075 threads.